# open excel workbook from memorystream

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to open an excel workbook from a memorystream. I have a web url of the excel file, what I do is I download the data from the url, then save it into a memorystream, but I am not sure how to open the workbook from the stream, here is how my code works so far.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

byte[] fileArray = wc.DownloadData("url is inserted here");

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileArray);
```

But from here I'm not sure how to go about reading the data from the stream to create the workbook, it doesn't seem like the spreadsheet document from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478410 works the way I want it to, any assistance or pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SpreadSheetDocument has an [Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562185) static method overload that takes stream as param for document source, just add to your code :

```
var doc = SpreadSheetDocument.Open(ms, isEditable);
```

Comment: It seems to say that isEditable doesn't exist in the current context when I try that method

Comment: this is just example, with second parameter you can choose will returned object be editable, for exmaple for read only use : SpreadSheetDocument.Open(ms, false);

Comment: But how do you get that excel to open up on the screen?

Comment: @user890332 you don't, not with just SpreadSheetDocument, you are asking another question, search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=display+excel